How can I get mypy working in Vim, Neovim or LunarVim?
I'm using LunarVim. And I want to use mypy in it, but don't know how to configure it. I think that I need to know first if mypy works like pyright, like dynamically. I removed pyright and I want to try mypy. I installed mypy from :MasonInstall inside LunarVim. I think that if I could know at least the neovim way of doing that. Cause I've used some neovim way to configure to guide the LunarVim configuration. And it works. So I installed mypy, and this is the config, but I don't know if it's ok. Here it is:
lvim.builtin.treesitter.ensure_installed = {
  "python",
}

local formatters = require "lvim.lsp.null-ls.formatters"
formatters.setup { { name = "black" } }

local linters = require "lvim.lsp.null-ls.linters"
linters.setup { { command = "flake8", args = {"--ignore=E203"}, filetype = { "python" } } }

linters.setup {
  { name = "mypy" },
  {
    name = "shellcheck",
    args = { "--severity", "warning" },
  },
}

lvim.plugins = {
  "AckslD/swenv.nvim",
  "stevearc/dressing.nvim",
}

require('swenv').setup({
  post_set_venv = function()
    vim.cmd("LspRestart")
  end,
})

lvim.builtin.which_key.mappings["C"] = {
  name = "Python",
  c = { "<cmd>lua require('swenv.api').pick_venv()<cr>", "Choose Env" }
}

-- require'lspconfig'.pyright.setup{}
require'lspconfig'.mypy.setup{}

vim.opt.backup = true
vim.opt.undofile = true
vim.opt.undodir = "~/.lvim/undodir"
vim.opt.backupext = ".bak"
vim.opt.swapfile = true
vim.opt.directory = "~/tmp"
vim.opt.wrap = true
vim.opt.linebreak = true

